# Bottle server POST options from listbox to SQL database

Tags: python, sql, post, bottle

I currently have a button, that when clicked, it creates two variables. These hold the selected options from a list box. Then I am attempting to POST these into my database via the bottle script, however it doesnt work. Can someone explain to me why?

The HTML/JQuery code for the button is this:

```
$("#btnStartEvent").bind("click", function () {
        var selectedStudents = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');
        var selectedEvent = $('#event_options option:selected');


        alert(selectedEvent); 
        $.post( "/send_data", { eventIDPost: selectedEvent},function(data ) { 
        alert( data ); 


});
```

And my bottle code that handles this POST is:

```
@post('/send_data')
def send_data():
    postdata = request.body.read() 
    events_id = request.forms.get("eventIDPost") 
    sql = "INSERT INTO tblResults VALUES('{}')".format(events_id)
    run_sql(sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if bottle `@post` is broken, but referencing to

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.route

and updating the api method to below:

```
@app.route('/send_data', method=['POST'])
def send_data():
```

started listening to the API calls.Otherwise it was **405** error

Also please refer https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post("/send_data", { "eventIDPost": 1 })
   .done( function (data) {console.log(data)});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you that the `@post` is not broken. I use it every single day.

```
from bottle import post, request

def merge_dicts(*args):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in args:
        result.update(dictionary)
    return result

@post('/send_data')
def send_data():
    return merge_dicts(dict(request.forms), dict(request.query.decode()))
```